# Is there a difference between using moment(Date.now()) and simply using moment()?

Tags: momentjs

Is there a difference between using `moment(Date.now())` and simply using `moment()`?

```
console.log("Moment (now):", moment(Date.now()));
console.log("Moment:", moment());
```

Both result in the same output:

> Fri Feb 15 2019 17:26:53 GMT+0000 (Greenwich Mean Time)

Comment: moment() by default returns current date and moment of any date,  it returns date in full format, both returns same output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`moment()` generates the current date as a moment instance, and `moment(Date.now())` casts the current Date object to a moment object, so yes it is the same!